# Can I distribute an app for test built with StoryBoard when target is 4.3?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, distribution, adhoc

I have built an application with xcode 4.5.2 using a Storyboard. Finally I was able to build for deployment of 4.3 but when I follow the instructions on how to distribute the app for beta testing, I get to the point I need to archive the app for iOS Device. When I do that I get an error that Stortyboards are unavailable for version 4.3 and prior. Is there a way to get around it or should I build the app without a Storyboard?

Thanks,
  Simon

Comment: Does the 4.3 version use the storyboard or have you coded it so it does something different under that version?

Comment: Yes it does. I did not make any change to support 4.3 differently from higher versions.

Comment: But storyboards aren't supported under 4.3 so how do you hope it will work if you do get it onto the device?

Comment: I thought it might be that Storyboards are helping during the builds but the final code generated can run on all iOS versions.

Comment: Nope; there are specific storyboard classes it uses; http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: If I understand correctly, in order to build apps for iOS 4.3 and higher I have to build them without using the Storyboards...

Comment: You mean 4.3 and **lower**?  And yes; iOS 4.3 and lower don't support storyboards so you cannot use them.

Comment: I meant that if I want to support iOS 4.3 and higher to 6 (but including 4.3) I need to build the app without a Storyboard.